# String length issue in java

Tags: java, string, stored-procedures

I am getting data from a DB procedure that returns an XML in an output param, When I execute this procedure into DB it returns the complete XML, but when I execute it using java, it only prints 4000 characters. Here is my code:

```
String sql = "{call SP_NAME(?)}";
try {
    CallableStatement stmt = DataAccess.databaseConnection
            .prepareCall(sql);
    stmt.registerOutParameter(1,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

    stmt.execute();
    String result=(String)stmt.getNString(1);               
    S.O.P(result);//Printing result
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

What is the reason for this? Can anyone help me to find out the issue?

Comment: Can't you check the String length with the length() function???

Comment: Which database is this?

Comment: length of my string is greater then 4000(i think about 4050 characters) but im getting only 4000 characters into result. this is my issue.

Comment: it's sql server, but i think its not issue of DB,

Comment: Have you tried to use `Types.Clob` instead of `Types.VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem i used two output param in procedure, both returns the result of XML and on java side i just concatenated both to get complete result, this solved my problem, hope this will help someone. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

How is your return value defined in your stored procedure? Chances are it is defined as a varchar(4000). If that's the case, your problem lies there.

If that's not the case, please look at the limits of your data structure.

If that's not the problem, have you tried debugging what your sql server driver returns?

Comment: i already checked both above things and not issue there, can you please explain what to check in driver ?

Comment: Sometimes drivers also put limits on the things they can send back to the client. Try putting a tool like p6spy between your application and SQL Server. That way you can see which call is performed and what data is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try by registering Output parameter as CLOB Type

> stmt.registerOutParameter(1,java.sql.Types.CLOB);

Answer (score 0):

I solved this changing `Types.VARCHAR` to `Types.LONGNVARCHAR`:

```
//Set OUT parameter
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.LONGNVARCHAR);
```

and also I read that it works using `Resultset`.

Link to another StackOverflow Question
[Output parameter from SQL Server stored procedure truncated at 4000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160157/output-parameter-from-sql-server-stored-procedure-truncated-at-4000-characters)