# Output parameter from SQL Server stored procedure truncated at 4000 characters

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a problem with the output parameter of a stored procedure when it contains more than 4000 characters. The response seems to be truncated by the JDBC driver? How can I get the full result?

The stored procedure answers with the complete response (> 4000 characters) but I can not open it from Java. I have tried both jTDS and Microsoft's JDBC driver 6.0. Here is my code:

```
CallableStatement pstmt = con.prepareCall("{call sp_horus_get_consultorios_stv(?)}"); 
pstmt.registerOutParameter(1, -1); 
pstmt.setString(1, ""); 
pstmt.execute(); 
String sp_horus_get_consultorios_stv = pstmt.getString(1);
```

This works with stored procedures in sybase.

Comment: You haven't given us enough info.  However, the magic number 4000 makes me think you have a varchar, which has a max char count of 4000.

Comment: This is my code: 
CallableStatement pstmt = con.prepareCall("{call sp_horus_get_consultorios_stv(?)}");    
pstmt.registerOutParameter(1, -1);
pstmt.setString(1, "");
pstmt.execute();
String sp_horus_get_consultorios_stv = pstmt.getString(1);

This works with stored procedures in sybase. The answer is complete

Comment: yes it looks like VARCHAR, for more it must be CLOB (or BLOB) which handles differently

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments section.  Update your question with it, and make sure it's formatted so it renders as code.

Comment: Which JDBC driver are you using? jTDS, perhaps? If so, then [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/513/) might be of interest.

Comment: Sorry, the description was not clear. The stored procedure answers the complete response but I can not open it from java.

Comment: Use the jdbc 6.0 microsoft and jtds drivers but none worked

Comment: why not use a resultset?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to recreate your issue using Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.x. I found that I could avoid the problem by commenting out the `setString` call:

```java
try (CallableStatement pstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call usp_horus_get_consultorios_stv(?)}")) {
    pstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.LONGNVARCHAR); 
    //pstmt.setString(1, "");  // disabled
    pstmt.execute(); 
    String sp_horus_get_consultorios_stv = pstmt.getString(1);
    System.out.println(sp_horus_get_consultorios_stv.length());  // > 4000 characters
}
```

Unfortunately, that fix did not solve the problem under jTDS 1.3.1. It appears that jTDS still suffers from the limitation described [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/513/). So, for jTDS it appears that we have to do something like this:

```java
String sql = 
        "DECLARE @out NVARCHAR(MAX);" +
        "EXEC usp_horus_get_consultorios_stv @out OUTPUT;" +
        "SELECT @out;";
try (
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql)) {
    rs.next();
    String sp_horus_get_consultorios_stv = rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println(sp_horus_get_consultorios_stv.length());  // > 4000 characters
}
```

Comment: Yes, commenting on that line returns the complete result. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your output parameter is of type NVARCHAR(8000), which is the maximum explicit number allowed, and outputs a 4000 character Unicode string lenght (2 bytes per char).

However, and lucky you, there another possibility : NVARCHAR(MAX), that basically allows an infinite string lenght (well, not infinite, but almost : 
[What is the maximum number of characters that nvarchar(MAX) will hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270049/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-characters-that-nvarcharmax-will-hold)

You should change your output paramater type to NVARCHAR(MAX).

Happy coding ;)

Comment: is nvarchar(max) el output parameter

Comment: no its in your database the format the value is saved in. @pauldaubian this has nothing to do with the database. its a java problem she has

Comment: You have to step into SQL Server and modify the Stored Procedure _sp_horus_get_consultorios_stv._ If you want to post it in your initial question we can help you modify it so the output is correct.